# Cannot update parent class states from child class stack navigator in react native

Tags: react-native

Parent class :

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      StatusBar
    } from 'react-native';
    
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    
    import LoginScreen from './AuthScreens/LoginScreen';
    import RegisterScreen from './AuthScreens/RegisterScreen';
    import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen/HomeScreen';
    import themeStyle from './themes/theme.style';
    
    
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    
    class App extends Component {
    
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.toggleLoginState = this.toggleLoginState.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          isLogin:false
        }
      }
    
      toggleLoginState() {
        // this.setState({
        //   isLogin: true
        // });
        alert("toggling login status");
      }
    
      render(navigation) {
        if(this.state.isLogin){
          return(
            <HomeScreen />
          );
        }
        else {
          return(
            <NavigationContainer>
              <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor={themeStyle.PRIMARY_COLOR_DARK}/>
              <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login"
                screenOptions={{
                  headerShown: false
                }}>
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} toggleLoginState={this.toggleLoginState}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} toggleLoginState={this.toggleLoginState}/>
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          );
        }
      }
    }
    
    module.exports = App;
```

child class :

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import theme from '../themes/theme.style';

import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

class LoginScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isUserBoxFocused : false,
            isPassBoxFocused : false
        };
    }

    userBoxHandler = () => {
        if(isUserBoxFocused){
            this.setState({
                isUserBoxFocused : false
            });
        }
        else{
            this.setState({
                isUserBoxFocused : true
            });
        }
    }

    passBoxHandler = () => {
       if(isPassBoxFocused){
            this.setState({
                isPassBoxFocused : false
            });
       }
       else{
            this.setState({
                isPassBoxFocused : true
            });
       }
    }

    alertBox = () => {
        alert("login status toggling from login");
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View
                    style={styles.header}
                >
                    <Image 
                        style={{width:200,height:200}}
                        source={require('../images/profile.png')}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                        Welcome!
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.desc}>
                        Sign In to Continue
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.footer}>   
                    <View style={styles.inputBox}>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <Feather name="user" size={20} 
                               color={this.state.isUserBoxFocused?theme.PRIMARY_COLOR_MED:theme.PRIMARY_COLOR_DARK}
                            />
                            <TextInput 
                                style={styles.input} 
                                placeholder={'username or email'}
                                onFocus={() => userBoxHandler()}
                                onBlur={() => userBoxHandler()}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={{height:1,backgroundColor:'gray'}}/>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <Feather 
                                name="lock" size={20} 
                                color={this.state.isPassBoxFocused?theme.PRIMARY_COLOR_MED:theme.PRIMARY_COLOR_DARK}
                            />
                            <TextInput 
                                style={styles.input} 
                                placeholder={'paasword'}
                                onFocus={() => passBoxHandler()}
                                onBlur={() => passBoxHandler()}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signInButton}
                        // onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('BaseScreen')}
                        onPress = {this.props.toggleLoginState}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.signInText}>SIGN IN</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => {navigation.navigate("Register")}}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.registerHere}>
                            Not a User? <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>Register here</Text>
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container :{
        height:'100%',
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'white',
    },
    header : {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        // backgroundColor:'red'
    },
    footer : {
        // backgroundColor:'blue',
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'flex-end',
        paddingVertical:40,
        paddingHorizontal:40
    },
    welcome : {
        fontSize:50,
        fontWeight:'bold',
        marginBottom:10,
        color:theme.PRIMARY_COLOR_DARK
    },
    desc : {
        fontSize:18,
        color:theme.SECONDARY_COLOR_DARK
    },
    inputBox : {
        backgroundColor:theme.BACKGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT,
        borderColor:theme.PRIMARY_COLOR_DARK,
        borderWidth:1,
        borderRadius:10,
        marginBottom:30
        // padding:10
    },
    row : {
        flexDirection:'row',
        padding:10,
        alignItems:'center',
    },
    input : {
        padding:10,
        flex:1,
        // backgroundColor:'blue'
    },
    signInButton : {
        backgroundColor:theme.SECONDARY_COLOR_DARK,
        borderRadius:10,
        padding:15,
        alignItems:'center',
        marginBottom:25
    },
    signInText : {
        fontSize:25,
        fontWeight:'bold',
        color:'white'
    },
    registerHere : {
        fontSize:15,
        alignSelf:'center',
        marginBottom:20,
        color:theme.PRIMARY_COLOR_DARK
    }
});

module.exports = LoginScreen;
```

I want to create a login flow. when users log in from the login screen it will directly switch to HomeScreen. For which I am trying to use state in parent class as 'isLogin' and wants to toggle this state from LoginActivity class. But unable to do so nothing happens on clicking Login Button in LoginScreen. I tried to pass toggleLoginState to child class and control the parent class state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly pass an event to the child component from the navigator root. According to the pattern you have figured your parent class and navigator root, you have to use `initialParams` attribute inside `Stack.Screen`. This attribute is accepting an object then you have to pass your event as an obejct.

Then change you code from

```
<Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} toggleLoginState={this.toggleLoginState}/>
<Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} toggleLoginState={this.toggleLoginState}/>
```

to

```
<Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} initialParams={{toggleLoginState : this.toggleLoginState}}/>
<Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} initialParams={{toggleLoginState : this.toggleLoginState}}/>
```

In the child component, the event that was bound to the params have to be accessed using `route.params` of child `props` and call the event using the property that was used in `initialParams` to set the event to the object.

```
loginEventHandler (){
   const {route} = this.props;
   route.params.toggleLoginState();
}
```

Then call this when login button triggers.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.signInButton} onPress = {this.loginEventHandler}>
     <Text style={styles.signInText}>SIGN IN</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```